# How to reduce scope to prevent variable from being modified

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have the following variable:

```
var a = [30,6,26,49,3,9,28];
```

And the following two functions:

```
function init(data) {
  var modifiedData = data.reverse().slice(1, data.length).reverse();
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Init: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [30, 6, 26, 49, 3, 9]

function last(data) {
  var modifiedData = data.reverse().slice(0, 1);
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Last: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [28]
```

If I call each function after the other like this:

```
init(a);
last(a);
```

I get the following output from the 2nd function:

```
Last: 28,9,3,49,26,6,30
[30]
```

Because apparently the 1st function is applying the **reverse()** on the data and the 2nd function seems to inherit the **reverse()** from the first function.

How do I use those two functions successively, while using the same variable as reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.reverse` reverses the actual array (before you clone in with `.slice()`). Forget about the reverses, you can do that with array.slice directly:

```js
var a = [30,6,26,49,3,9,28];

function init(data) {
  console.log("Init: " + data);
  var modifiedData = data.slice(0, -1);
  console.log(modifiedData);
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Init: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [30, 6, 26, 49, 3, 9]

function last(data) {
  console.log("Last: " + data);
  var modifiedData = data.slice(-1);
  console.log(modifiedData);
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Last: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [28]

init(a);
last(a);
```

When you run it, have a look at the browser console to see the result.

`-1` is the same as `data.length - 1`.

Comment: Thank you nils, had forgot about the "-1" tricks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Insert at the first line of function:

```
data = data.slice(0); // make copy
```

Comment: Is this "best practice"?

Comment: Also should it be: "var data = data.slice(0);

Comment: yes, it is best practice, no, data is the parameter of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using reverse **after** slice. [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) clones the array.

```js
var a = [30,6,26,49,3,9,28];

function init(data) {
  document.write("Init: " + data);
  var modifiedData = data.slice(0, data.length - 1);
  document.writeln(" " + modifiedData);
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Init: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [30, 6, 26, 49, 3, 9]

function last(data) {
  document.writeln("Last: " + data);
  var modifiedData = data.slice(data.length - 1, data.length);
  document.writeln(" " + modifiedData);
  return modifiedData;
}

// Output should be:
// Last: 30,6,26,49,3,9,28
// [28]

init(a);
last(a);
```

Comment: If I run your code I get "[28, 9, 3, 49, 26, 6]" from the init function. But I should get "[30, 6, 26, 49, 3, 9]", so everything except the last array item.

Comment: What about now? I added slice(0) to clone the array the first time.

Comment: You don't need the `reverses` or a second `slice` at all, see below